# Protractor: How to feed URL in Cmd Line

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium-webdriver, command-line, protractor

Currently to run a Protractor test - the URL is in the spec file specified. Now I know I can put it in the spec.js:

```
browser.get('www.google.com');
```

To run this I would do:

```
protractor conf.js
```

Does Protractor have a way to feed the URL in Command Line? Like this:

```
protractor conf.js "www.google.com"
```

I know its possible to specify the URL in a config.properties file or in conf.js. If it can be run like this in command line it'd give a lot of options. Maybe feed several URLs in an array and output the logs as well.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is also a `--baseUrl` *command-line argument*. It is going to be prepended to the url you pass to `browser.get()`:

```
protractor conf.js --baseUrl=https://google.com
```

Now, if you do `browser.get("/")`, you are going to get the Google's index page. If you do `browser.get("/someotherpage")` - "some other page" is going to be opened.

Answer (score 1):

`protractor conf.js --params.url=yourUrl`

and in `conf.js` (or anywhere you want to use the value) invoke it by `browser.params.url`